# What is this pipe that is next to our house and HVAC?

Tags: hvac, pipe, exhaust

We bought a house and it has this next to the HVAC. It looks like a pipe that drains into this cement box that has another pipe inside the cement box going into the ground. There is electricity running to whatever it is. There is also a pipe next to it coming out of the ground and going above the house(I’m guessing an exhaust pipe of some sort). Anyways we are interested to know what it is because it rained and there is a bunch of standing water in it now that is becoming a nesting ground for mosquitoes.

[pipe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WBJOJ.jpg)

Comment: Please [edit] to include a picture. Use the sun&mountains icon above the edit box. And take the [tour] and register your account so that you can edit even if not coming from the same device/browser you posted the question from.

Answer (score 1):

That most likely is the condensation drain for your AC.

It appears to drain into a catch basin.  That basin is emptied by a sump pump. (That is what the electric in the basin is for.)
If water is collecting and not being emptied, the sump pump is not working.

Normally the condensation is just allowed to run out onto the ground to be soaked into the soil / evaporated. Why you have a catch basin is unknown to me.

The mosquitoes can be treated with [granules](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0001AUF8G) .

You may try calling an HVAC company and ask them if this basin is something common in your area.